# IBM Connections Profile API to retrieve "about me"

Tags: ibm-connections

I'm trying to access the "about me" field of a user's Connections 5 profile for a synchronization with our third party tool.

However, I don't seem to be able to find this field anywhere. I tried to access a user's (also my own) profile on `/profiles/atom/profile.do?userid=5EEA50A0-0643-7A7D-C125-7D3800334349` but he returned feed does not include the desired information.

If i query `profiles/atom/profileService.do` I will get various link elements for my user profile none of which seem to include the "about me" field. However the result of this query includes a `snx:editableFields` section which contains a `<snx:editableField name="description">` element which might refer to the desired "about me". Sadly, this field is empty for this request, although I know that my user has some information stored for "about me". All other fields in the snx:editableFields section do also not contain any data, so maybe this information is just structure description rather than really meant to hold the data?

Has anyone successfully tried to retrieve the "about me" or maybe "background" (snx:experience?) user properties via the API? Am I just missing the right call in the API documentation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this URL

```
https://<your host>/profiles/atom/profileEntry.do?output=vcard&format=full&userid=<userid>
```

You will have two fields in the response

```
X_EXPERIENCE:&lt;p dir="ltr"&gt;FOOBAR&lt;/p&gt;
X_DESCRIPTION:&lt;p dir="ltr"&gt;ABOUTLUCKY&lt;br&gt;
```

Comment: Thanks! 

Actually what I did was just adding the `format=full` parameter to the request i mentioned in my question `/profiles/atom/profile.do?userid=5EEA50A0-0643-7A7D-C125-7D3800334349&format=full`. Now that request also contains the full information. Did I just miss this in the documentation or is this some kind of "hidden feature"?